# Partitioning Images containing sub images of slightly different dimension

Tags: image-processing

I have a PDF file that contains 3 pages of microphotographs that are subdivided
into subimages of several individual micrographs.  For the first two pages the individual
photomicrographs are arranged in a 3x2 array (labeled A-F) whereas on the last page,
the last element of what would be an another 3x2 array is missing so that only micrographs
labeled A-E appear.

I seek to save these micrographs (array elements) each as a single image file that
can be subsequently associated with data from the image captions.  When imported the
original files contain a single image each so I seek to subdivide each page into
its natural component micrographs minimizing retaining maximum resolution with minimal distortion of the proportional heights and widths.

Here is a down sampled version of the 6 micrographs on the first page:

[image: image6]

Using the following, I nearly succeed in partitioning the single image
containing 6 micrographs arranged in 3 rows of 2 micrographs each so
that each sub image can be saved as an individual file and associated
with the appropriate figure captions, eventually all bundled within
a Dataset.

```
subimages = Flatten[ImagePartition[image6, {210/3}]]
```

[image]

However, note that the two micrographs labeled "C" and "D" actually contain a small
portion of the pixels in the previous two micrographs.  I've attempted to alter
the value passed for the individual image widths, but increasing or decreasing this
value typically as well as playing with Ceiling/Floor functions and padding results either in an additional number of unwanted partitions, or too few
partitions in which some of the individual micrographs are lost.  It seems this
arises from the individual micrographs not being all the same image dimension.  Similar
results emerge when using the larger original files, although the values for widths
are necessarily larger.

How can one partition the original image so that the desired effect is achieved even
when the sub images are not uniformly sized?

Ideally, an automatic solution is sought that does not require manual tweaking
in such situations.  I have tried to segment the original image into a list of components
following the suggestions for questions 35249 and 109154, but using either MorphologicalComponents[] or ImageForestingComponents[] fail to get all parts of all desired
sub images.  Usually 4 or 5 of 6 micrographs, can be obtained but unfortunately both functions
break some individual micrographs into many undesirable smaller
components.  These not easily joined to recreate the missing "whole" components sought,
because the components of these missing elements typically appear in arbitrary order
and there may be several hundreds or thousands of them.  Thus, making them difficult to identify and recompose into a single sub image (micrograph).

Croping and then arranging cropped parts into a list might work, but I can't figure out how
to tell ImageCrop how to determine the border dimensions of the desired sub images before the
command is executed without considerable trial and error that needs to be avoided to achieve a fully automated process.

Comment: are the image labels separately available or are they extracted from the images themselves?

Comment: Image labels appear in the sub images A-F or A-E, etc.  The captions are in text still within the PDF document containing the images but not yet addressed, since want first to be able to segment sub-images properly and then start the task of associating the labels with the text in the figure captions.

Answer (score 1):

I start with an image panel. You can use your example.

```
img = Import["C:\\Work\\typical_image_panel.jpg"];
```

[image]

The main reason I chose [this](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10163-019-00947-w/figures/3) image using Google search is that it has labels and all subpanels have varying degrees of feature granularity. It may or may not be important for your case. Then I ran the following command; (more experimentation required with thresholds). You can run this in steps to see what's going on at each step.

`t1 = MorphologicalBinarize[img, {0.96, 0.96}] // ColorNegate //  ImageSubtract[img, #] & // DeleteSmallComponents // ColorNegate`

[image]

The label (c) is attached with a few small pixels and was not removed highlighting the complexity of such tasks, but let's keep going.

```
HighlightImage[img, ImageLines[GradientFilter[t1, 1], 0.1, 0.15]]
```

The ImageLines[..] above can be evaluated separately to get these line parameters for further processing.

You can read this excellent [article](https://www.mathematica-journal.com/2012/02/17/perimetric-complexity-of-binary-digital-images/) on perimetric complexity if you haven't done so already. I hope this answer provides you some pointers to get started.

[image]